# Problems with the module pafy (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pafy

Code:

```
import pafy

video = pafy.new(url)
best = video.getbest()
playurl = best.url
```

The problem is that the `pufy` module works for a while, and then non-working URLs are passed to the variable `urlplay` causing errors

[Error Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyCVD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use a try-except around the function call that requests the non-working URL so the error doesn't make your code crash.

For example, if the `getbest()` fucntion is where the URL request is made, use the following:

```
import pafy

video = pafy.new(url)

try:
    best = video.getbest()
except (TheExceptionYouWantHandled) as exception:
    print(exception)
else:
    playurl = best.url
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't make any sense in my code